# Best architecture for reading data from a Rabbitmq queue and saving it to a database using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

I'm working on a project where I'm dumping data from a prod application onto a rabbitmq queue for logging and on the other side of the queue I need to pop logged record off the queue and put them in a db.

I'd like to use the same or similar model classes on the other side of the queue so the app that logs the data and the app that reads the logged data and saves it use the same class definitions anyone have thoughts on this?

I'm thinking of just using another rails app on the other side of the queue but I'm concerned about performance if the data flow gets big.

I'm thinking though that since this app will only need to read data from the queue and save it, that rails may be overkill (though I may also build in a 'reporting' app on top of that app to do reporting on the data that's been logged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord can be used outside Rails. I think I [blogged about that](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://ollehost.dk/blog/2005/11/20/activerecord-outside-of-rails-handy-db-tool/) a few years ago.

Comment: Yeah. But I'm hoping to find a lighter implementation. Thanks!